# VBA - Find Cell from List (column)

Tags: vba

First time asking a question here. Finding it hard to find an answer even if I'm sure it already exists but hoping you can help me out.

So I have cell A1 in Tab1 that I need to find in column A of Tab2 and make it the active cell and select the entire row. How do I do that?

It seems pretty simple but for some reason, I can't get to this solution. Can someone help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. Find our lastrow value on Tab2
2. Loop through all the cell values in column A of Tab2. If one of those cell values equals our value in A1 on Tab1, activate Tab2 (if not already active) and select the entire row.

`Sub Test()`

```
lastrow = Worksheets("Tab2").Cells(Worksheets("Tab2").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To lastrow
    If Worksheets("Tab2").Range("A" & i).Value = Worksheets("Tab1").Range("A1").Value Then
        Worksheets("Tab2").Activate
        Worksheets("Tab2").Rows(i).EntireRow.Select
        Exit For
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

EDIT: This numbered list formatting is giving me a headache...

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
Sub Test()
    Dim found As Range
    With Worksheets("Tab2")
        Set found = .Range("A1:A" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Find(What:=Worksheets("Tab1").Range("A1").Value, LookIn:=xlValues, lookAt:=xlWhole)
        If Not found Is Nothing Then
            .Activate
            found.EntireRow.Select
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```